# Error:(15, 32) error: cannot find symbol variable webview

Tags: android

cannot find symbol webview

```
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview); //get the error here
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.miWebView);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.android.com");

    }
```

In my activity_main.xml

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/miWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</linearLayout>
```

I don´t know where is the error.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 setContentView(R.layout.webview);
```

to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You must set `activity_main.xml` layout at `setContentView(...)`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to set layout of Activity because `activity_main.xml` is layout name instead of `webview.xml`.